# How do I prevent activation of in-app subscriptions when user logs in with a different account?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I am developing an Android/iOS application that uses Ionic and [In App Purchase 2](https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) to allow users to purchase a monthly or yearly subscription. This subscription is then tied to their account (which they register from the application) using the purchase token, together with the expiration date.

The problem I am facing is that, when *user A* purchases a subscription with *phone A*, the Google / Apple account associated with *phone A* and *user A* is both associated with the purchase, so when *user A* logs out, and *user B* logs in on the app with the same phone, *user B* has not yet purchased a subscription, so when they try to purchase, In App Purchase 2 sets the status automatically to Approved / Owned, since the Google / Apple account associated with *phone A* has already purchased the subscription, and this fools the app into thinking that *user B* has also purchased the subscription, so activating the subscription for *user B*.

How do I prevent multiple users from logging into the app and re-using the subscription associated with the Google / Apple account? I would be very thankful for any hints or tips regarding this.

This might be a confusing question, and I apologize if that is the case.

I would be grateful for any assistance. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

A classic problem with in-app purchases! For this, what you really need is a server to manage the subscription status for your user IDs, and don't rely on the device receipt after the initial purchase occurs. In the example you provided, when user B logs in and tries to purchase, they'll receive a message from Apple that the subscription is already owned, and you don't do anything, user B doesn't get access.

The real fun begins when user B tries to then do a restore - since you should have some restore functionality in your app. For restores, you should send the receipt to your server still, but you'll want to check if the same receipt is already associated with another user before giving access to user B. If you see that user A already has the same receipt, you can either return an error to user B, or transfer the receipt from user A to user B - giving user B access and revoking access for user A.

The details of building this out would be a much larger post, but hopefully this can point you in the right direction. There are also third-party tools like [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) that are built for this type of thing (Disclaimer: I work there).

More info on building an IAP server: https://www.revenuecat.com/blog/altconf-subscriptions-are-hard

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for your answer! We actually already use an API server, and use that to verify purchases and associate purchases with our app's users. But I have not thought about checking if a receipt is already used by another user. Thanks for reminding me! I guess I will also need to find a method to only recognize "owned" status when the user clicks on the Purchase button, since if the "owned" status is recognized without the user even clicking on it, then an error like "That purchase token is already taken" would suddenly show. Thank you very much! I'll check your link, too.

Comment: Ah sounds like you've gotten some of the hard part out of the way! If you first make sure you have some rules to not save duplicate receipts on your server, then you can add some logic to associate only a single User ID to each receipt.

Comment: Hey @enc_life, what about the case where the user buys a subscription on one app account, then switches to another app account and wants to upgrade the subscription to a higher tier one (not buy the same one)? In this case the upgrade would succeed and Apple wouldn't prevent it. How do we handle this case? If we allow it then the user would be charged but he wouldn't receive any content which is bad UX.

Comment: @AmerHukic up to you. I show a "This receipt is already in use by another customer" message to the user.

Comment: @enc_life I have a similar problem, how I can make it possible for in-app user B to purchase the same subscription? I actually use RevenueCat for Flutter. Calling purchase for the same subscription just results in Play Store telling me I have already purchased it. I thought calling setAllowSharingStoreAccount(false) might help with it, but it didn't

Comment: @enc_life on iPhone thought, it worked exactly as expected, another purchase was triggered

Comment: In-app purchases are billed through the device account, not your "user A" or "user B" accounts. So if the device account already has a subscription you can't purchase another one - just a limitation of in-app purchases.

Comment: I was under this impression as well, from reading the documentation, but then I saw multiple apps, Medium for example, support this somehow. I can see this being possible by creating multiple identical subscriptions and displaying them depending on whether the account has purchased something in the past. But I don't think this was the implementation for some reason, seems too complex

Answer (score 1):

With Native Play Billing Library 2.2+, you're able to tie the obfuscated app account id by calling [setObfuscatedAccountId](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setobfuscatedaccountid) (and [setObfuscatedProfileId](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/BillingFlowParams.Builder#setobfuscatedprofileid) if necessary) to the purchase when launching the purchase flow. So your backend and app will both be able to identify if which app account a purchase is binded to. But to leverage this feature, you might need to code by yourself since I didn't see In App Purchase 2 has that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

can you have it so they purchase tokens that can then be used to activate an account on your end?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, that's not how our system works, and Apple explicitly prevents such system (like what happened to Epic Games) so I don't think we can do that.

Comment: ah i though i had read something like that before, i would have just comment but im <50 on this site

Comment: No problem! I really appreciate hearing your thoughts on this. That's actually a great way to fix this problem! Unfortunately, Apple (and maybe Google) does not allow such a system, so we can't do that. But please don't let that stop you from sharing your thoughts! Every idea counts, so don't mind it when people get angry and dismiss comments even though they are valid ideas.

Comment: also was the epic games thing about circumventing the app store with their own payment system. say you have a game where they sell gems(token) in the app store then you use the gems to buy membership

Comment: Ah, yeah, if I remember correctly (I may be wrong), Epic Games made a way so you can purchase in-app currency from their website and then use that currency in-game, so yeah, it was circumventing the App Store. But we use subscriptions instead of one-time purchases, so even if we were able to do that, it would be inconvenient to buy every month / year. (Besides, unfortunately, we plan to actually use Play Store / App Store purchases, anyway :) )